# How do I force config overrides to refresh?

Tags: 8, configuration

I've setup a system of dynamic config overrides using a service tagged with `config.factory.override`. This override overrides the `system.site` `name` configuration.

I have a form that upon submission invalidates the necessity for that override. An email is sent as part of this submission handler, that includes a token for `[site:name]` and `[site:url]`. The token swap happens as part of another module that I'm not coding, so I cannot set this up to retrieve the original non-overridden values.

I have found that if I call `drupal_flush_all_caches()` in my submission handler, the emails show up with the correct values for the original non-overridden values.

I don't want to take this sledgehammer approach however. But I cannot figure out what to invalidate to force the config values to regenerate rather than use the originally overridden values.

I've tried invalidating the static cache. I've tried invalidating cache tags for `system.site` and `system.site.name`. And a lot of other various cache invalidations. However, the only thing I can find that actually works is `drupal_flush_all_caches()`.

Does anyone know how I can force the config system (or maybe the Token system?) to rebuild config (or token) values?

Comment: Try with ConfigFactory::reset('system.site') take a look https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21ConfigFactory.php/function/ConfigFactory%3A%3Areset/8.9.x

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the mails still show up with the overridden config value.

Comment: and `CacheBackendInterface::invalidate('system.site')` doesn't work either ?
the cache with cid `system.site` contain name, mail, langcode, slogan ...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: Try [token_clear_cache()](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/token/-/blob/8.x-1.x/token.module#L163)

Comment: And introducing some new config to have this name set and new token to print it?